# Store view category description

Tags: magento2, category, store-view

We want to check or load the category description from the store view itself, instead of the general.

By default it is loaded as `<?= $category->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription() ?>`

How can we check or get the store view value?

We use the following code:

```
class Category extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
        protected $_registry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    )
    {        
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function getCurrentCategory()
    {        
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
    }

    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {        
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
    }    

}
```

Comment: The current category object loaded by **registry** already included description data by the current store. So, <?= $category->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription() ?> should return the category description for the current store. Btw, since you only need category data, you should use View Model instead of using a block class that extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template to improve performance. Read more about View Model at Magento official document https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/view-models/

Comment: @TuVan thanks a lot! That’s true, but if the store view is empty it shows the default value. And we want to check that and only show the store view value. Can you provide a example of how you should modify it to use the View Model instead?

Comment: which page do you want to implement this change on?

Comment: @TuVan Thanks! On the category overview page

Comment: I’ve wrote the solution below, did you check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To **force** get only the category description by **store scope** and ignore  the category description from the **global scope**, you should use a **resource connection** to directly run the query to get the data from the database.

Additionally, in case you need to write **a new** class to get the category description by store, you should use a View model instead of a Block class that extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template to improve performance. Read more about View Model at Magento official document https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/view-models/

**Steps to achieve your requirements:**

1. Create a View model or a Block class to write a function to get the category description by store.
2. Call the function from a View model/ Block class to display the category description by store in the template file.

**Implementation:**

Assuming your vendor name `Magetu`, your module name `Catalog`:

- In the layout XML file (`catalog_category_view.xml`), modify block to declare a new View model.
  See the following examples for reference:

```
<block name="magetu.example" template="Magetu_Catalog::example.phtml">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="categoryDescription" xsi:type="object">Magetu\Catalog\ViewModel\CategoryDescription</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

```
<referenceBlock name="category.description">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="categoryDescription" xsi:type="object">Magetu\Catalog\ViewModel\CategoryDescription</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

- Here is the code for the View model class:

```
<?php
namespace Magetu\Catalog\ViewModel;

use DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Configuration\Item\ItemInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetup;
use Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class CategoryDescription implements ArgumentInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Registry $registry
     */
    private $registry;

    /**
     * @var AdapterInterface
     */
    private $connection;

    public function __construct(
        Registry $registry,
        ResourceConnection $resource,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->connection = $resource->getConnection();
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function getCategoryDescription()
    {
        $currentCategory = $this->registry->registry('current_category');
        $catalogCategoryTextAttributeTable =
            $this->connection->getTableName('catalog_category_entity_text');

        $selectCategoryDescription = $this->connection->select()
            ->from(
                ['catalog_category_entity_text' => $catalogCategoryTextAttributeTable],
                ['value']
            )->where(AttributeInterface::ATTRIBUTE_ID . '= ?', $this->getCategoryDescriptionAttributeId())
            ->where('store_id = ?', $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId())
            ->where('entity_id = ?', $currentCategory->getEntityId());

        return (string)$this->connection->fetchOne($selectCategoryDescription);
    }

    private function getCategoryDescriptionAttributeId()
    {
        $selectAttributeCode = $this->connection->select()
            ->from(
                ['eav_attribute' => $this->connection->getTableName('eav_attribute')],
                ['attribute_id']
            )->where('entity_type_id = ?', CategorySetup::CATEGORY_ENTITY_TYPE_ID)
            ->where('attribute_code = ?', 'description');

        return $this->connection->fetchOne($selectAttributeCode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code within the block and helper are likely to be locked to the current store so you will need to do something like this to pull out a specific level :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$categoryFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
$categories = $categoryFactory->create()->setStoreId(STOREID)->getCollection(); // this is a collection of categories so you will need to loop through it
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    var_dump($category->getDescription());
}
```

I don't recommend using ObjectManager of course but the above should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! See my edit, because we load it using _registry. How can we modify this?

Comment: you would need to combine my code with yours,  $this->_registry->registry('current_category')->getId() would give you the id of the current category.

So edit my example like this would give you the description on the store level
foreach ($categories as $category) {
if ($this->_registry->registry('current_category')->getId()  == $category->getId()){}
    var_dump($category->getDescription());
}

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple, in fact.

Suppose you already acquired a specific Category (by calling `$block->getCurrentCategory()` or by any how), you can retrieve its store-specific description by giving it a Store ID.

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category */
$category = $block->getCurrentCategory();
$category->setStoreId(1); // set Store ID
$description = $category->getDescription(); // get store-specific description value
```

That should work just fine.

**Side case**

Should `$category->getDescription()` returns `NULL`, that means your `$category` object was not fully loaded with attributes. In that case, you'll have to load the Category object again to have it populated with attribute values.

*Using Repository*

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository */
$category = $categoryRepository->get($categoryId, $storeId); // pass store ID as the second parameter
$description = $category->getDescription();
```

*Using Collection*

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory */
$categoryCollection = $categoryCollectionFactory->create()
    ->setStoreId(1) // set Store ID
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*') // required, otherwise attribute values like description will not be loaded
    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['eq' => $categoryId]); // optional, if you want to load a single category only
foreach ($categoryCollection as $category) {
    echo $category->getDescription();
}
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks a lot! See my edit, because we load it using _registry. How can we modify this?

Comment: My answer should cover it for you. Firstly try the first code snippet, if it returns NULL while you can make sure that the category has store-specific description value, move on to the side case below, pick either one that best suits you. I would recommend using Repository over Collection though.